# Convex set and MVT

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $U\subset\mathbb{R^{n}}$ an open set, and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function s.t. $\forall x\in U \quad\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x)=0$.
>
> Assume U is a convex set, and prove that then $f$ does not depend on $x_1$ (meaning $f(a)=f(b)$ if $a$ and $b$ only differ in the first component.

This is my attempt:

$U$ is a convex set. hence, by MVT, for $(x_1,x_2),(x_3,x_2)\in U$, there's a $0<c<1$ such that:

$f(x_1,x_2) - f(x_3,x_2) = Df((x_3,x_2) - c(x_1-x_3,0))(x_1-x_3,0)$. Therefore,

$f(x_1,x_2) - f(x_3,x_2) = (Df(x_3,x_2) - c\cdot Df(x_1-x_3,0))(x_1-x_3,0)$.

And I'm not sure how to proceed from this point (if I haven't made any mistakes). I'm trying to prove that right side of the equation is equal to zero, and to conclude that $f(x_1,x_2) = f(x_3,x_2),\quad \forall x_1,x_3$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the points $x \in U$ as $x = (x_1,\xi)$ with $\xi =(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. You want to show that $f(x_1,\xi) = f(x'_1,\xi)$ for all $(x_1,\xi), (x'_1,\xi) \in U$.

Consider two distinct points $(x_1,\xi), (x'_1,\xi) \in U$. Since $U$ is convex, the line segment connecting $(x_1,\xi), (x'_1,\xi)$ is contained in $U$. W.l.o.g. we may assume that $x_1 < x'_1$. Thus
$$g : [x_1,x'_1] \to \mathbb R, g(t) = f(t,\xi)$$
is a well-defined differentiable function. Its derivative at $t$ is
$$g'(t) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(t+h) - g(t)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(t+h,\xi) - f(t,\xi)}{h} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(t,\xi) = 0.$$
The MVT shows that for some $c \in (x_1,x'_1)$
$$ \frac{g(x'_1) - g(x_1)}{x'_1-x_1}= g'(c)$$
and we conclude from $g'(c) = 0$ that
$$f(x_1,\xi) = g(x_1) = g(x'_1) = f(x'_1,\xi) .$$